# Prepend default option to SelectList not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, insert, selectlist, prepend

In my controller, I have:

```
var parentSubjects = new SelectList(_context.Subject, "SubjectId", "SubjectName");
parentSubjects.ToList().Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = "None", Value = "" });
```

Nothing happens when the 2nd line is executed. I expect a blank item to be inserted at the 0th index in the list. What am I missing?

Comment: `ToList` creates a new separate list.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my post to include the solution.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. However, do not edit answers into questions. Add a self answer to the post instead. Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `parentSubjects.ToList()`, you are creating a new copy of the list from `parentSubjects` and the `Insert` operates on that copy. Since you didn’t save the list, the new item is lost.

You can fix this by saving the list created by `ToList()`, and using that:

```cs
var parentSubjects = new SelectList(_context.Subject, "SubjectId", "SubjectName").ToList();
parentSubjects.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Text = "None", Value = "" });
```

If you are using the `asp-items` tag helper in your view, there is also a different option that will avoid having to create a `SelectListItem` for your blank/default option. You can directly add the option to the HTML there:

```
<select asp-for="SelectedSubjects" asp-items="Subjects">
    <!-- simply add the option directly here; the options from
         `asp-items` will be added below -->
    <option value="">None</option>
</select>
```